# "Save and Continue Edit" button is not working properly

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, module

I have a form in my module, and now I want to add the new button to it i.e. `Save and Continue Edit` button.

I added this button but it is working partially, means it is saving the values in the database but not redirecting to the current page.

Here is my file code.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'blog';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_article';
    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label','Save Article');
    $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', 'Delete Article');
$this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
             'label' => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
             'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
             'class' => 'save' 
         ), -100);
         $this->_formScripts[] = "
             function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action + 'back/edit/');
             }
             ";
    $this->setId('blog_edit');
}
```

Now what should I need to do it properly.

Here is my controller file.

```
<?php
class Vertax_Blog_Adminhtml_ArticleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('blog/article')
            ->_addBreadcrumb('Article Manager','Article Manager');
   return $this;
 }
  public function indexAction()
  {
     $this->_initAction();
 $this->_title($this->__("Vertax_Article"));
     $this->renderLayout();
  }
  public function editAction()
  {
       $articleId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
       $articleModel = Mage::getModel('blog/article')->load($articleId); 
   $categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', $articleId); 
      if ($articleModel->getId() || $articleId == 0)
       {
         Mage::register('article_data', $articleModel);
         $this->loadLayout();
         $this->_setActiveMenu('blog/article');
         $this->_addBreadcrumb('article Manager', 'article Manager');
         $this->_addBreadcrumb('Article Description', 'Article Description');
         $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
         $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('blog/adminhtml_article_edit'))
              ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('blog/adminhtml_article_edit_tabs'));
         $this->renderLayout();
       }
       else
       {
             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                   ->addError('Article does not exist');
             $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
   }
   public function newAction()
   {
      $this->_forward('edit');
   }
   public function saveAction()
   {
     if ($this->getRequest()->getPost())
     {
       try {
             $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
     //echo "<pre>";print_r($postData); exit;
     $articleModel = Mage::getModel('blog/article');
     $imgFilename = NULL;

    if($_FILES['image']['name'] != '') 
      {
                try { 
                     $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                     $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
         $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                     // Set media as the upload dir
                     //$media_path  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
         $media_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'blog' . DS;
                     $imgFilename = $media_path . $postData['image'];
                     // Upload the image

                     $uploader->save($media_path, $_FILES['image']['name']);
                    }
                 catch (Exception $e) 
        { 
                     Mage::log($e);
                     $this->_redirectError(502);
                    }
        $data['image'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
              } 
     else 
      {        
        if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1)
         $data['image'] = '';
        else 
        unset($data['image']);
      }
        $imageModel=Mage::getModel('blog/image');

                if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0 )
                  $articleModel->setCreatedTime(
                  Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                        ->gmtDate());
                  $articleModel
                  ->addData($postData)
                  ->setUpdatedTime(
                         Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                         ->gmtDate())
                  ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                  ->save();
          $lastid = $articleModel->getId();
        $imageModel->setArticleId($lastid)->setImage($data['image'])->save();
          foreach($postData['category_id'] as $cat_id)
        {
         $categoryModel = Mage::getModel('blog/category');//print_r($categoryModel); exit;
         if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0 )
                     $categoryModel->setCategoryId($cat_id)->setArticleId($lastid)->save();
             $categoryModel->setCategoryId($cat_id)->setArticleId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->save();
        }
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                           ->addSuccess('successfully saved');
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                            ->setarticleData(false);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;

          } 
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                              ->addError($e->getMessage());
             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                ->setarticleData($this->getRequest()
                                ->getPost());
             $this->_redirect('*/*/edit',
                        array('id' => $this->getRequest()
                                            ->getParam('id')));
             return;
            }
          }
          $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
      public function deleteAction()
      {
          if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0)
          {  $articleId=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            try
            {
                $articleModel = Mage::getModel('blog/article');
                $articleModel->setId($this->getRequest()
                             ->getParam('id'))
                             ->delete();
        $categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', array('eq'=>$articleId));
        foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {
            $cat->delete(); }

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                           ->addSuccess('successfully deleted');
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
             }
             catch (Exception $e)
              {
                       Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                            ->addError($e->getMessage());
                       $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
              }
         }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
       }

public function massDeleteAction()
{
$catIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if (!is_array($catIds)) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select item(s)'));
} else {
try {
foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
$cat = Mage::getModel('blog/article')->load($catId);
$cat->delete();
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', array('eq'=>$catId));
    foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {
    $cat->delete();
        }
}
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted',
count($catIds))
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
}
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

public function massActiveAction()
{
$catIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if (!is_array($catIds)) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select item(s)'));
} else {
try {
foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
Mage::getSingleton('blog/article')
->load($catId)
->setStatus('Active')
->setIsMassupdate(true)
->save();
}
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
$this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($catIds))
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
}
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

public function massInactiveAction()
{
$catIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if (!is_array($catIds)) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select item(s)'));
} else {
try {
foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
Mage::getSingleton('blog/article')
->load($catId)
->setStatus('Inactive')
->setIsMassupdate(true)
->save();
}
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
$this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($catIds))
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
}
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
}
?>
```

Here is my `form.php`

```
<?php
class Vertax_Blog_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{
   $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
   $this->setForm($form);
$form->setDataObject(Mage::registry('article_data'));
   $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('article_form',
                                   array('legend'=>'Article Configuration'));
    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text',
                   array(
                      'label' => 'Name',
                      'class' => 'required-entry',
                      'required' => true,
                       'name' => 'name',
                ));

$fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
          'label'     => 'Status',
          'name'      => 'status',
          'values'    => array(
            array(
            'value'     => 'Active',
            'label'     => 'Active',
            ),
            array(
            'value'     => 'Inactive',
            'label'     => 'Inactive',
            ),
           ),
          ));
$isElementDisabled = false;
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $fieldset->addField('store_ids', 'multiselect', array(
            'name' => 'store_ids[]',
            'label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
            'required' => true,
            'values' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
             'note'      => 'Hold CTRL to select multiple'
            ));
    } else {
        $fieldset->addField('store_ids', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'store_ids[]',
            'value' => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId()
        ));
    }
//TODO: replace the categories

$fieldset->addField('category_ids', 'multiselect', array(
        'name' => 'category_ids[]',
        'label' => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Categories'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Categories'),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'values' => Mage::helper('blog')->getCategoryOptionValues(true),
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
        'index' => 'category_ids',
         'note'      => 'Hold CTRL to select multiple'
    ));
/*$wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(
                array('tab_id' => $this->getTabId())
            );*/
$configSettings = array( 'add_widgets' => false, 'add_variables' => false, 'add_images' => false,  'files_browser_window_url'=> $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/');

$fieldset->addField('summary', 'editor', array(
            'name'      => 'summary',
            'style'     => 'min-width:615px;',
            'required'  => false,
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Summary'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Summary'),  
            'config'    => $configSettings,
            'wysiwyg'   => true
        ));

$fieldset->addField('content_html', 'editor',
                   array(
                      'label' => 'Content',
          'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Content'),
          'style'     => 'min-width:615px;',
                      'class' => 'required-entry',
                      'required' => true,
                      'name' => 'content_html',
          'config'    => $configSettings,
          'wysiwyg'   => true
                   ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBlogPostData()) {

        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBlogPostData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBlogPostData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry('article_data')) {
        $data =  (!Mage::registry('article_data')->getId())? $this->getDefaultValues() : Mage::registry('article_data')->getData(); 
        $form->setValues($data);
    } 
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
 /*if ( Mage::registry('article_data') )
 {
    $form->setValues(Mage::registry('article_data')->getData());
  }
  return parent::_prepareForm();
 }*/
}
  ?>
```

here is the code for the `form.php` in edit

```
<?php

 class Vertax_Blog_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Form extends
                      Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
 {
 protected function _prepareForm()
 {
     $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array(
              'id' => 'edit_form',
              'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
              'method' => 'post',
      'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
             )
          );
  $form->setUseContainer(true);
  $this->setForm($form);
  return parent::_prepareForm();
 }

 protected function _prepareLayout()
 {
parent::_prepareLayout();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: We need to see the controller code. That is where the redirect is happening or not working properly.

Comment: I added my controller code in the question. now can you see why it is not happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the problem is that in your controller you missed this code in `saveAction()`.

Place it after saving model and success message.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
    $this->_redirect(
        '*/*/edit',
        array(
            'id' => $oModel->getId(),
            'store' => $sStoreId
        )
    );
    return;
}
```

Comment: my form id is correct here, I checked that, I still dont understand what to do. any ideas..

Comment: Please run `console.log($('edit_form').action)` and see what is inside.

Comment: I didn't understand this, where should I put this code.

Comment: Answer was updated.

Comment: before saving my url is this `http://127.0.0.1/magento_new/index.php/blog/adminhtml_article/edit/id/7/key/19e644dc23ac70765583800007983765/` and after clicking the button console shows this `http://127.0.0.1/magento_new/index.php/blog/adminhtml_article/save/id/7/key/e13958c44adc4353f7b69f8e66bd5d65/back/edit/`

Comment: What is happening here, can you tell me. I didn't understand it.

Comment: Can you please add form class code to the question?

Comment: I added the form class in the question.

Comment: Also please add `Vertax_Blog_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Form`.

Comment: question is updated.

Comment: Answer updated. Hope that will fix your problem.

Comment: Guys I have a similar issue. Could you help me please? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164960/back-end-grid-edit-page-buttons-dont-work-properly