# Creating a new Form in Admin panel, but Save button is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i'm currently working over a custom extension.

I've created a custom Edit Form in the admin panel and here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

The `Save Item` button is just like dead. When i click on it just nothing happens, no errors even no page loading/reloading.... just nothing.

The `Delete Item` button is working fine and it is deleting what it must delete.

Here is the code that i think is responsible for my strugle:

I Here is my Edit.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container

{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Save Item'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Delete Item'));
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('smsnotification_data') && Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getId() ) {
            return Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__("Edit Item '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Add Item');
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the file path by the class..

Here is what i have in my Form.php file:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    {


        protected function _prepareForm()
            {
                $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                        'id' => 'edit_form',
                                        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                        'method' => 'post',
                                     ));
                $this->setForm($form);
                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('smsnotification_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item information')));

                $fieldset->addField('Receiver', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Receiver',
                     ));

                $fieldset->addField('Phone', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Phone',
                    ));

                $fieldset->addField('Date', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Date',
                    ));

                if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData() )
                    {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData());
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData(null);
                    } elseif ( Mage::registry('smsnotification_data') ) {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getData());
                    }
                    return parent::_prepareForm();
            }
    }
```

Here is what i have in my Status.php file:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container


{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Here is what i have in: SmsorderstatusesController.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml_SmsorderstatusesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('SMS Center'))->_title($this->__('SMS Center'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $smsnotificationId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $smsnotificationModel  = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification')->load($smsnotificationId);

        if ($smsnotificationModel->getId() || $smsnotificationId == 0) {

            Mage::register('smsnotification_data', $smsnotificationModel);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('smsnotification/items');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status_edit'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification');

                $smsnotificationModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setReceiver($postData['Receiver'])
                    ->setPhone($postData['Phone'])
                    ->setDate($postData['Date'])
                    ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification');

                $smsnotificationModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    /**
     * Product grid for AJAX request.
     * Sort and filter result for example.
     */
    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
               $this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_smsnotification_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }
}
```

Here is also my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <smsnotification>
                <file>smsnotification.xml</file>
            </smsnotification>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Database structure:

[image]

I've done much of all i've done by this guide: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Can you please tell me why my `Save Item` button is not working, where is the problem and how i can fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

NOTE2:
Picture of grid table after saving new item.

[image]

Comment: I have issues with your use of double underscore constructor in your classes. I believe this would prevent the magento constructor of the parent classed from firing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your setForm to the bottom above the call to parent. I added setUseContainer as well.  See if this works for you.

The setUseContainer outputs the `<form>` tags so if your button isn't working then this may be the cause.

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{


    protected function _prepareForm()
        {
            $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                    'method' => 'post',
                                 ));


          // This moved to the bottom
          //$this->setForm($form);
          ////

$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('smsnotification_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item information')));

            $fieldset->addField('Receiver', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
                'class'     => 'required-entry',
                'required'  => true,
                'name'      => 'Receiver',
                 ));

            $fieldset->addField('Phone', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
                'class'     => 'required-entry',
                'required'  => true,
                'name'      => 'Phone',
                ));

            $fieldset->addField('Date', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
                'class'     => 'required-entry',
                'required'  => true,
                'name'      => 'Date',
                ));

            if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData() )
                {
                    $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData());
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData(null);
                } elseif ( Mage::registry('smsnotification_data') ) {
                    $form->setValues(Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getData());
                }


                // Add these two lines

                $form->setUseContainer(true);
                $this->setForm($form);

                ////

                return parent::_prepareForm();
        }
}
```

---

Try replacing this in your controller:

```
 $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));

 $smsnotificationModel->setReceiver($postData['Receiver'])
                ->setPhone($postData['Phone'])
                ->setDate($postData['Date'])
                ->save();
```

Comment: As always you are the Magician! That seems to be working but now i get error like `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (id='10')' at line 1` Any suggestion or more information needed?

Comment: I may need more info, but in your saveAction, try changing `$smsnotificationModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))` to `$smsnotificationModel->setData('ID',$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')))`.  I seem to remember that your field was `ID` and not `id` in your database structure but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I've added an image of the table structure and the ID is not ÌD`but it is `id`. Tell me which files i must show you? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my edit at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Thanks once again! Now it says `Item was successfully saved` but it actually is not making the change to the result. It is not making the changes when it says it does!

Comment: NOTE! When i tryed to create a new row. The whole procedure goes perfect and then when i'm returned to the Grid table with the message `Item was successfully saved` i can see that it is creating an empty insert. Like it is not getting the data from the form inputs. I've uploaded a picture into my answer!

Comment: I've added a detailed question for the new problem. Can you please check it out here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57473/creating-new-adminhtml-form-but-saveaction-not-working . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good solution , worked like a charm
moving this line $this->setForm($form); made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seem to be with your html form tags don't exist or action is blank... View your browser source and look for a form with id='edit_form`

`VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit_Form` should be more like

```
class <Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_<Module>_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                        'id' => 'edit_form',
                                        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                        'method' => 'post',
                                     )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

`<Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_<Module>_Edit_Tab_Form` with your form field

Also change this

```
$this->_objectId = 'id';
$this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';
```

to

```
$this->_objectId = 'id';
$this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_smsnotification';
```

Comment: When i change it i get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php on line 129`

Comment: Can you please help me out resolve the problem ? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check you js error console? Could you inspect element what is the href for the save button?

Comment: Here is the source code of the button after inspect element: http://pastebin.com/gVewzdqt Also when i open the console and i click on the button nothing happens. No errors are given to the console.

Comment: Do you think i have the answer here will resolve my problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/save-and-continue-edit-button-is-not-working-properly ?

Comment: Also i did not know did you notice that i have removed `->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('blog/adminhtml_article_edit_tabs'));` From the controller and i haven't any `Tabs`

Comment: Take a look at more detailed explanation of my question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56355/save-button-not-working-new-adminhtml-form

Comment: Take a look at my update

Comment: I've added a detailed question for the new problem. Can you please check it out here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57473/creating-new-adminhtml-form-but-saveaction-not-working . Thanks in advance!