# Creating new Adminhtml Form, but saveAction() not working!

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and currently i'm working on a custom Magento extension!

Here is a screenshot of the Form:

[image]

When i hit `Save Item` i got this:

[image]

As you can see the `saveAction()` has not saved the changes.

When i place: `Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getPost());` to see if the form is working i get this:

```
2015-02-17T13:25:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [form_key] => zj9E8FpNOCyFIqaT
    [Receiver] => Veni
    [Phone] => 359884685063
    [Date] => 2015-02-05 19:06:44
)
```

By this i think the form is okey.

Let me show you all the code i have in my Extension!

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container


{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Grid.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smsnotification/smsnotification_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
          $this->addColumn('id', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('ID'),
              'align'     =>'right',
              'width'     => '50px',
              'index'     => 'id',
          ));

          $this->addColumn('Receiver', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
              'align'     =>'left',
              'index'     => 'Receiver',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('Phone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Phone',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Date',

        ));


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Edit.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container

{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Save Item'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Delete Item'));
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('smsnotification_data') && Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getId() ) {
            return Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__("Edit Item '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getReceiver()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Add Item');
        }
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Edit/Form.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    {


        protected function _prepareForm()
            {
            $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                    'method' => 'post',
                                 ));

                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('edit_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item information')));

                $fieldset->addField('Receiver', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Receiver',
                     ));

                $fieldset->addField('Phone', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Phone',
                    ));

                $fieldset->addField('Date', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Date',
                    ));

                if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData() )
                    {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData());
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData(null);
                    } elseif ( Mage::registry('smsnotification_data') ) {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getData());
                    }
                // Add these two lines


                $form->setUseContainer(true);
                $this->setForm($form);

                ////

                return parent::_prepareForm();
            }
    }
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/SmsorderstatusesController.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml_SmsorderstatusesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('SMS Center'))->_title($this->__('SMS Center'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $smsnotificationId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $smsnotificationModel  = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification')->load($smsnotificationId);

        if ($smsnotificationModel->getId() || $smsnotificationId == 0) {

            Mage::register('smsnotification_data', $smsnotificationModel);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status_edit'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {
                Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

                $smsnotificationModel->setReceiver($postData['Receiver'])
                ->setPhone($postData['Phone'])
                ->setDate($postData['Date'])
                ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification');

                $smsnotificationModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    /**
     * Product grid for AJAX request.
     * Sort and filter result for example.
     */
    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
               $this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_smsnotification_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <smsnotification>
                <file>smsnotification.xml</file>
            </smsnotification>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/Smsnotification.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_Smsnotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification','id');
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/Smsnotification/Collection.php:

```
<?php 
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_Smsnotification_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');    
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Smsnotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');
    }

}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/sql/smsnotification_setup/install-1.0.0.php:

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Receiver` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
    ");
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

This are all files which i have in my Extension, exept adminhtml.xml and system.xml.
If you think they are important to be shown i'll show them.

So do you can you see the problem why it is not making the save properly ?
Can you help me out fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DB structure is wrong:

```
$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Receiver` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
    ");
```

Should be:

```
$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receiver` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
    ");
```

Notice the column names in my version do not start with a capital!

EDIT: Captilization is important for Magento's ORM to work.

To go into more details: refer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareDataForTable()

This method above runs the describe mysql command on the DB and get's the column names. In your case it get's Receiver while it has is stored as _data['receiver'] = 'xyz' in our object. Just due to the caps difference, magento does not recognize that setReceiver corresponds to Reciever in DB. It should be reciever. Similarly something like first_name should be set as setFirstName() on the object.

To look at how data is stored in an object var_dump($object->getData()) where $object is any Magento object that is loaded from the DB.

Comment: In the database table they are starting with capital. So do i have to change them also or it will work on this way ?

Comment: You will need to change them in the database, also.

Comment: Why it is important for them to start with lowercase? Also do i have to change after that them in all places where i describe them as `Receiver` for example, should i change it to `receiver` ?

Comment: See Edit.........

Comment: I changed them to lower case and now i have the following error while i'm trying to submit the edit `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (id='13')' at line 1`. Any advice ?