# Back-End "Save and Continue Edit" Button Works Partially

Tags: magento-1.9, module, grid, custom, backend

I created a custom module and the "Save and Continue" button on the back-end grid edit page works partially. Either it saves the values and doesn't stay on the same (edit) page or it stays on the same page but doesn't save the values
(this happens when I uncomment the "setLocation" line in __construct() function).
How can I fix the button to both save the values and remain on the same page? Please help.

Here is the save action in controller file:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    //if (!$postData) return $this->getResponse()->setBody('$postData is empty');
    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        $model = Mage::getSingleton('cpstest_productcomment/cps');
        $model->setData($postData);

        try {
            $model->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The comment has been saved.'));

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false)) {
                 $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
                    'id' => $model->getId(),
                    '_current' => true
                ));
            } else {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
            return;
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('An error occurred while saving this comment.'));
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCpsData($postData);
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibilities: `saveAction()` is not called at all, `$postData` is empty, keys in `$postData` don't match any of the fields in `$model`. Suggest to add debug code `if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) { ... } else { Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addNotice('empty $postData');}`

Comment: @kiatng  I think saveAction is being called, because the Save button works well. Where should I add the debug code? In controller file? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need evidence that `saveAction()` is being called. The debug code can be in `public function saveAction()`. Simple way to do it's with `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addNotice('some debug info');` in anywhere of the code. If you want evidence that it is being called, place that statement right at line 1 in  `public function saveAction()` with the message 'I am here'.

Comment: Hi @ kiatng . I added the debug code just like you said and when I press "Save" the text shows up, but when I press "Save and Continue Edit" it doesn't show up.

Comment: It means that `$this->getCurrentUrl()` in `'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getCurrentUrl()}')",`  doesn't return the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in your admin block constructor

```
$this->_formScripts[] = " function saveAndContinueEdit(){
    editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following function in your Edit.php

```
public function getCurrentUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/cps/save', array(
        '_current'  => true,
        'back'      => 'edit',
        'tab'       => '{{tab_id}}'
    ));
}
```

[edit1] Changed '*/*/save' to '*/cps/save'

[edit2] Add this to your controller after `..->addSuccess();`

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false)) {
     $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
        'id' => $model->getData('primaty_index_column_name'), // to replace with actual name
        '_current' => true
    ));
} else {
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}               
return;
```

Comment: Hi @kiatng. How do I know the value of "tab_id"? What should I put there? Thanks

Comment: `tab_id` is set in the browser's js, in `function saveAndContinueEdit()`. You do not need to do anything if you only have one tab.

Comment: I added the function and it's redirecting to a blank page and again doesn't save any value.

Comment: You need to compare the URLs on the __Save__ button and __Save and Continue__ button in your browser. The controller and action of both should be the same. If you do not know how to construct the correct one, paste both URLs here.

Comment: Here is the URL for the "save and continue" - http://formodulecheck.dev/index.php/admin/cps/edit/id/28/key/4589e8722321fe3c7d49cacaba64fa79/
And for the "save" button - http://formodulecheck.dev/index.php/admin/cps/index/key/1c59b2ba03822fa18249eec16e9d02a2/

Comment: It looks like your controller is IndexController.php. I edited the code, please try.

Comment: Hi @kiatng . I changed the code and it took me to the 404 page and the url is ..../index.php/cps/index/save/back/edit/tab/%7B%7Btab_id%7D%7D/id/27/key/13861c680a2fa15c908ecdfc1b8d4ee6/

Comment: In that case, try _'admin/cps/save'_

Comment: That gave this url ..../index.php//cps/save/back/edit/tab/%7B%7Btab_id%7D%7D/id/27/key/f151c00bf2ee7eb453d5b886265db551/     and a 404 error again ((

Comment: In that case, try _'\*/cps/save'_

Comment: That goes to a blank page and doesn't save any values.

Comment: What is the class name of the controller? Could it be that it cannot get pass this line `if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {`? If `$postData` is null, what does your code do?

Comment: I think it won't do anything when it's null, but it's definitely not null.

Comment: Why not put it to test? Place this in the beginning of `public function saveAction() {$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); if (!$postData) return $this->getResponse()->setBody('$postData is empty');`

Comment: Hi @kiatng, thanks for your efforts. I put the test code and it says $postData is empty.

Comment: Let me mention, I made changes to the codes and now it does save the values but doesn't stay on the same page.

Comment: Added _edit2_ in my answer to redirect to the edit page.

Comment: I added that code, but again it works like "Save" button,  saves the value and goes back to the grid page. I updated the codes in my question.

Comment: One possible reason is that this `id' => $model->getId(),` is incorrect. Can you paste the URL when you are editing the model?

Comment: Sure, here is the edit page url:   http://formodulecheck.dev/index.php/admin/cps/edit/id/28/key/d4334dc5285705a010ef3d9d40a49ea3/
And here is the url after pressing "save and continue"
http://formodulecheck.dev/index.php/admin/cps/index/key/f3c208871cdb76abd4e955ee801539ee/

Comment: Your URL points out that `$model->getId()` is probably incorrect. Try `$model->getEntityId()`. If that doesn't work, please provide the column name that you use for primary index in the table in the DB. Then modify the magic getter to `$model->getData('primaty_index_column_name')`, you need to replace the `primaty_index_column_name` with the actual name.

Comment: Hi  @kiatng. I tried both versions and again it saves the values but then redirects to the previous page. My primary key is just "id".  
Maybe something's wrong in my Edit.php file where I define the 'save and continue' button?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try this to force redirect to edit page: `if (1 || $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false)) {`. If this works, then there is no `back` param in your URL. If it doesn't, then `$model->getId()` is returning something unexpected. You should then find out what it is.

Comment: Hi @kiatng,  At last it worked!! I placed this if (1 || $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false)) { in your "edit2" answer.  Thanks so much for all your time! BUT, now the "save" button works like "save and  continue" as well. It remains on the same page after saving the values. What can I do with that?

Comment: In a word, either "save" button works correct or the "save and continue"  :(

Comment: It means that there is no `back` param when the form is submitted with _Save and Continue_. This is easily fixed by adding the `back` param in the submission URL. I see that you edited my answer and the _getCurrentUrl_ is no longer there.  And I see that you have now `editForm.submit($('edit_form').action + '*/*/edit/');`. You need to remove that and restore _getCurrentUrl_

Comment: Or keep the offending code but change it to `editForm.submit($('edit_form').action + 'back/1');`

Comment: Hi @kiatng, when I restore getcurrentUrl in the Edit php, the 'saveand continue' button redirects to a blank page and the 'save' button works incorrect, it redirects to "edit" page after saving the value.
I'm a little confused, could you please update your answer , so that I have a better clue on what to do? Thanks a ton.

Comment: And when I added this editForm.submit($('edit_form').action + 'back/1'); , both buttons worked like "saveandcontinue" , they both save values, but redirect to the same edit page.

Comment: Blank page means $postData is null, _Save_ button redirects to edit page means there is a param _back_. You need to solve either one of them. I.e., make sure the $postData is not null, or remove the _back_ param.